# How to append highest value from a text file to a list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm having trouble trying to figure out the code for a program I'm writing. I'm given a file with the format:

```
student_firstname
student_lastname
student_number
assignment_mark
midterm_mark
exam_grade
final_mark
```

Here is a sample:

```
Marilyn
Malone    
136238
88
72
70
Esther
Mulcahy
194563
25
45
91
William
Gray
110031
33
38
62
```

I'm trying to find a way to return the highest and lowest final_mark from all students. What I've done so far is:

```
infile = open(fileName, "r")
myList = []
name = infile.readline().strip()

passingGrades = 0
failingGrades = 0
avGrade = 0    

while name != '':
    highestGrade = [0, 'studentName']
    lowestGrade = [99, 'studentName']
    lastName = infile.readline().strip()
    studentNum = infile.readline().strip()
    assignGrade = infile.readline().strip()
    midGrade = infile.readline().strip()
    examGrade = infile.readline().strip()
    averageGrade = ((int(assignGrade) * 0.25) + (int(midGrade) * 0.25) +
                    (int(examGrade) * 0.50)) 

    def lowGrade(x):
        if x < lowestGrade[0]:
            lowestGrade.pop(0)
            lowestGrade.pop(0)
            lowestGrade.append(x)
            lowestGrade.append(name)
            lowestGrade.append(lastName)
        return lowestGrade   

    if averageGrade >= 50 and int(examGrade) >= 50:
        #print(name)
        passingGrades += 1
        avGrade += averageGrade

        if averageGrade > highestGrade[0]:
            highestGrade.pop(0)
            highestGrade.pop(0)
            highestGrade.append(averageGrade)
            highestGrade.append(name)
            highestGrade.append(lastName)
        else:
            pass

    else:
        failingGrades += 1
        avGrade += averageGrade

    lowGrade(averageGrade)

    name = infile.readline().strip()

finalAverage = avGrade / (passingGrades + failingGrades)

highFinal = ' '.join(str(x) for x in highestGrade)
lowFinal = ' '.join(str(x) for x in lowestGrade)
```

When the program is run using one of the text files, I get:

```
Number of passes: 9
Number of fails: 1
Average final grade: 64.55
The Highest Grade: 79.5 Patty Marshall
The Lowest Grade: 79.5 Patty Marshall
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Hi Galen, welcome to StackOverflow. I'm reading the question and finding it hard to understand what you're solving. What are you `pop`ping off the list, and then why are you appending other things to the list? What are `averageGrade` and `name` - they aren't defined?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst my bad, I’ve posted the full project code to put it into context a little better

Comment: Is there a file for each student, or if in a single file, how is each student entry separated (if at all)?

Comment: Cool. So what's the specific problem? You might want to add some `print` statements so you can debug more easily. Couple of notes: [1] you are resetting the `highestGrade` and `lowestGrade` variables every time you run through your while loop; [2] the `lowestGrade` variable is kind of emptied and then populated - probably simpler to just assign a new value to it; [3] the `lowGrade` function both changes the variable value *and* returns that value, which is confusing.

Comment: @leakybytes single file full of all the values listed, basically each student has 5 lines of the data listed, then the next student has 5 lines, and so on

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst added some print statements to hopefully explain this better

Comment: @leakybytes added an example to show what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you read a new student, you 'reset' the `highestGrade` and `lowestGrade` to their initial values (`0` and `99`, respectively).

```
while name != '':
     # stuff that happens for each 'name'
    highestGrade = [0, 'studentName']
    lowestGrade = [99, 'studentName']

    # ... do stuff ...

    # read new name
    name = infile.readline().strip()
```

Fix this easily by initializing those values *outside* of your loop.

```
highestGrade = [0, 'studentName']
lowestGrade = [99, 'studentName']

while name != '':
     # stuff that happens for each 'name'
```

---

In addition, your `lowGrade` method is unnecessarily complex and redundant. Instead of removing items from the list and then adding new items, just create a new list. And in fact, a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples) would be more appropriate than a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists), although both will work.

```
lowestGrade = (99, 'studentName')

def lowGrade(x):
    if x < lowestGrade[0]:
        lowestGrade = (x, name, lastName)
```

You don't need to return the `tuple`/`list` from this method, as you don't use the returned value at all.

Comment: thank you! ended up refactoring highest grade into a function using a tuple as well!

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you find a lowest grade you are removing 2 values from the list and adding 3. This means that the first value is never removed. Can you check if this works for you?

```
def lowGrade(x):
    if x < lowestGrade[0]:
        lowestGrade.pop(0)
        lowestGrade.pop(0)
        lowestGrade.append(x)
        lowestGrade.append(' '.join(name, lastName))
    return lowestGrade
```

Comment: The same applies to the highestGrade btw

Comment: tried this but I'm getting a typerror, join() only takes one argument

Comment: yeah, it should be .join((name, lastName)). Anyhow, Kirk got the right answer